Showing the viewValue rather than the value in Angular 14
Currently it shows the value down below, but I need the value in there to collect in the typescript to run through the stored procedure(s).
<div class="example-additional-selection2">
            <!--<select id="affinityprogramid" name="affinityprogramid" class="field select medium" tabindex="11" ngModel required #pid="ngModel">
  <option value="2"> Merchant card connect</option>
  <option value="9">Biz credit card credit reporting</option>
  <option value="28">Legal services</option>
  <option value="27">HR</option>
  <option value="3">NER</option>
  <option value="25">Peer Executive Groups</option>
  <option value="24">Net Coverage</option>
  <option value="26">Listenforce</option>
  <option value="22">HUB</option>
</select><p></p>-->
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-additional-selection">
              <mat-label class="example-additional-selection-no-border">Affinity Program</mat-label>
              <mat-select multiple class="example-additional-selection-no-border" #programids matNativeControl required [formControl]="selectFormControl" tabindex="3" [(value)]="selectedProgram">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let program of programsList" [value]="program.value" class="example-additional-selection2">
                  {{program.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
              <mat-error *ngIf="selectFormControl.hasError('required') || selectFormControl.invalid">Please choose an program</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div><small class="example-additional-selection-no-border">These are the programs selected: <b>{{selectedProgram}}</b></small></div>
</div>

Screenshot
I tried using {{program.viewValue}} but that obviously errored. New to angular, so trying to decifer typescript and formatting for hmtl.

If I understand your question, what you want the value selected for selectedProgram to be the text that showing in the option instead of the numeric value? If yes, the <mat-option>' should be with [value]="program.viewValue" instead of [value]="program.value".

That errors saying program doesn't exist in the ts file.

Hmmm, quite weird, if you can use program.value for [value] attribute, it shouldn't complain for program doesn't exist in the ts file.

What I am referring to is the text at the bottom in the  that refers to the {{selectedProgram}}.                     tabindex="3" [(value)]="selectedProgram"                         [(value)]

programsList: Program[] = [
{ value: '2', viewValue: 'Merchant card connect' },
{ value: '9', viewValue: 'Biz credit card credit reporting' },
{ value: '28', viewValue: 'Legal services' },
{ value: '27', viewValue: 'HR' },
{ value: '3', viewValue: 'NER' },
{ value: '25', viewValue: 'Peer Executive Groups' },
{ value: '24', viewValue: 'Net Coverage' },
{ value: '26', viewValue: 'Listenforce' },
{ value: '22', viewValue: 'HUB' }
];

I also want the viewValue  which is the description, not the value which is essentially the id
